# QML / QT: TableView Vertical ScrollBar (mouse works but touch does not on scrollbar)

Tags: qml, tableview

A one file, simple example is below that showcases my concern.  TableView flick area works as expected with mouse and touch.  It's the scrollbar that seems to not function properly.  Mouse allows you to click and drag the scrollbar handle and to click in the scrollbar background and the content area responds.  However, if you try to press in the scrollbar background or grab the scrollbar handle with touch...no response.  Why?  Suggestions on how to fix?

Thanks,
-Rich

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    width: 641
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        width: 640
        height: 200
        anchors.fill: parent
        TableView {
            id: tv
            horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
            verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "title"
                title: "Title"
                width: 100
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "author"
                title: "Author"
                width: 200
            }
            model: libraryModel1
            style:  TableViewStyle {
                decrementControl: Rectangle {
                    width: 0
                    visible: false
                }
                incrementControl: Rectangle {
                    width: 0
                    visible: false
                }
                scrollToClickedPosition: true
                handle: Rectangle {
                    visible: true
                    implicitWidth: 10
                    radius: width/2
                    color: "#2EA2EC"
                }
                scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
                    visible: true
                    width: 10
                    radius: width/2
                    color: "#DBDDDD"
                }
            }

            ListModel {
                id: libraryModel1
                ListElement {
                    title: "A Masterpiece"
                    author: "Gabriel"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "Brilliance"
                    author: "Jens"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "Outstanding"
                    author: "Frederik"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "A Masterpiece"
                    author: "Gabriel"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "Brilliance"
                    author: "Jens"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "Outstanding"
                    author: "Frederik"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "A Masterpiece"
                    author: "Gabriel"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "Brilliance"
                    author: "Jens"
                }
                ListElement {
                    title: "Outstanding"
                    author: "Frederik"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rich, I've the same problem. Did you find any solution? Thks. Cristiano

Comment: I did not.  Per Qt support:  Thank you for contacting Qt Support,

If your embedded device uses touch screen, the input for scrollbar is disabled when a touch input is used as it's not really practical and and flicking the view is usually preferred with touch input.

However, if you attach a mouse to your device the input works for scrollbar is it mainly ignoring the input that is not coming from a genuine mouse, but accepts it when a real mouse is used.